# submit done only after two click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to check the value before submit
so i tried the two method to do so but the same problem
the problem is that user need to click once again after check is true
i tried with chrome , firefox and IE and the same problem always
here index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        submitnow=false;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form#test").submit(function(e){
                //e.preventDefault(); //i test this way (here and line 17) with same problem line
                if(submitnow==false){
                        num=$("#num").val();
                        $.post("check.php",{num:num},function(result){
                            if(result=="true"){
                                alert("check return true");
                                submitnow=true;
                                $("form#test").submit();
                                //$("form#test").unbind('submit').submit();
                            }else{
                                alert("check return false");
                            }
                        });
                }
                if(!submitnow)
                    return false;
                else
                    alert("submitnow is true");
            });
        });
    </script>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="test" >
        <label for="num" >Num</label>
        <input id="num" name="num" type="text"  value="1" required/>
        </br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
<?php
echo (isset($_POST['submit']))?'submit done':'';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and here check.php

```
<?php
echo ($_POST['num']==1)?'true':'false';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form#test").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = this;
        var num = $("#num").val();
        $.post("check.php", {
            num: num
        }, function (result) {
            if (result == "true") {
                alert("check return true");
                submitnow = true;
                //don't do this as it will call the submit handler again
                //$("form#test").submit();
                frm.submit();
            } else {
                alert("check return false");
            }
        });
    }
    });
});
```

then change the id and name of the `submit` button

```
<input id="mysubmit" type="submit" name="mysubmit"/>
```

Comment: the same code is ok after change the name of the submit but why ?

Comment: after change the name it's the result from `print_r($_POST)` is `Array ( [num] => 1 )`

Comment: where is the submit button !

Comment: the main problem is if you have a input with name as `submit` then that element will be will assigned to the property `form.submit` so now `form.submit` is no longer a function.... thus the attempt to submit will fail

Comment: @robert try to assign a value to the submit button and try

Comment: same problem `<input id="submit2" type="submit" name="submit2" value="save"/>`

Comment: i made hidden input with name submit_2 and it's work

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: so it's ok if the submit input won't send with the `$_POST` array

Comment: it should be `Array ( [num] => 1 [submit2] => save )`

Comment: In the `check.php` request you are not sending the submit button so it won't be available.. again the actual form submit is done manually so again the submit button won't be sent

Comment: in that you can use a hidden variable to achieve that

Comment: i already used hidden input thanx man i would never try to change the name of the submit button

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("form#test").submit(function(e){
            //e.preventDefault(); //i test this way (here and line 17) with same problem line
            if(submitnow==false){
                    num=$("#num").val();
                    var formname = $this;
                    $.post("check.php",{num:num},function(result){
                        if(result=="true"){
                            alert("check return true");
                            submitnow=true;
                            formname.submit();
                            //$("form#test").unbind('submit').submit();
                        }else{
                            alert("check return false");
                        }
                    });
```

This will work for you. 
As you are submitting the inbuilt form two types.

Comment: the problem solved by change submit button name but now it doesn't send with the $_POST array

Comment: if you have explain to this please tell me